# Does converting character columns to factors save memory?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a 2.5 GB dataset, which is quite large for my 4GB memory. I wonder if converting character variables to factors will save space and processing time.

I would imagine that internally, factors will be stored in numeric with a lookup table for levels. But I am not sure how it actually works.

Comment: You are correct about the way factors are stored.  But the space savings is dependent on the number of factor levels and the length of the strings you're looking to convert.  You also might want to look at some of the big data packages like `ff`.

Comment: Converting to factor won't save space because characters are stored in a hash table.  Converting to factor may improve processing time--if whatever you're doing would convert character to factor anyway--but it really depends on what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clear explanation, Joshua. And thanks Justin for pointing to ff package.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich : post as answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Converting to factor won't save space because characters are stored in a hash table.  See section [1.10 The CHARSXP cache](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html#The-CHARSXP-cache) of [R Internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html).

Converting to factor may improve processing time if your code would need to convert to factor (running a regression, classification, etc.), but it won't improve processing time if you're doing string manipulation because it would have to convert the factor back to a character. So it really depends on what you're doing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your first sentence?  Or do you have a reference that provides details?

Comment: @Dason: Elaboration added. :)

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize it did that but that's nice to know.

Comment: I don't understand this really. When you do something like this: `x <- rep(c("x", "y", "z"), 1e6)`... `object.size(x)` gives a size twice as large as `object.size(factor(x))`. Am I doing something stupid? Or have I missed the point in some way?

Comment: @MadScone: They're nearly the same size for me using R-2.15.2 on 32-bit Win7, 32-bit Ubuntu, and 64-bit Ubuntu.  The only reason I would expect the results you report is if you're using R < 2.6.0.

Comment: I'm using R 2.15.2 64-bit Ubuntu so I don't know what's going on.

Comment: @MadScone is correct, the character vector is double the size for me as well.

Answer (score 7):

Storing categorical data as factors rather than as character vectors does save space when writing data to the disk:

```
## Create 2 two-million length vectors, one character and one factor
animalsChar <- c(rep("giraffe", 1e6), rep("pygmy chimpanzee", 1e6))
animalsFac  <- factor(animalsChar)

## Save them to two ".Rdata" files
charFile <- "char.Rdata"
facFile <-  "fac.Rdata"
save(animalsChar, file = "char.Rdata")
save(animalsFac, file = "fac.Rdata")

## Compare the sizes of the two files
file.info("char.Rdata", "fac.Rdata")["size"]
#             size
# char.Rdata 87390
# fac.Rdata   7921


## Clean up
unlink(c("char.Rdata", "fac.Rdata"))
```

Comment: Space in RAM and space on the HDD are different.  Check `print(object.size(animalsChar), units="Mb")`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich -- Thanks for the explanation. I had tried `object.size()` first, and wondered at its results. Seems like this still might come in handy in some situations.