# Code does not work since updating to new R version

Tags: r

New to R. My code worked fine until I updated from R 3.6.1 to R 4.0.2, getting the following error on following code:

```r
descriptive.dt = all_sub.tbl[,lapply(.SD,summary)]
```

> Error in dimnames(x) <- dnx : 'dimnames' applied to non-array

```
descriptive.dt[,c("Issuer_ID","Sector") := NULL]

descriptive.dt[,measure := c("Min","Percentile25","Median","Mean","Percentile75","Max")]
```

I have read bunch of things on the Q&A, still can't fix it.

**Notes:** `all_sub.tbl` is fine, I saved it as csv. It's some data that I am trying to summarize faster in min, 25th percentile, mid, mean, 75th, max. 9 columns with approx 100 rows of data. Can't get

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it easier to help you? (providing sample input with `dput()`, expected output, and code that can be copy-pasted and run as is)

Comment: A common issue when upgrading to v4 is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61950876/read-csv-doesnt-seem-to-detect-factors-in-r-4-0-0,